# how to get last updated record's id from table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My table will be modify by only one user and it may be modify after every second.
I want to get the last record's id and record is updated by user about a second or millisecond ago. can anyone help me how can i do this and i do not have any date/time column in the table.

Comment: Google for "SQL Magic Tables" that can help you out, with a bit use of triggers along the way

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the OUTPUT clause: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

There are other ways, but those are all vulnerable to race conditions. Output is part of the DML Statements implicit transaction and hence reliable.